# can you please suggest me how to retain the same picklist values after selecting the one since it is repeating each time on selection

Tags: selectoption

[image]

Posting my code here...

```
<apex:page standardController="Patient_Registration__c" extensions="soption09">
<apex:form id="myForm">
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!listvalue}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionlist}" rendered="true">
    <apex:actionSupport rerender="myForm" event="onchange"/>
</apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
<!--<apex:outputText value="{!selectedtext}"/>-->
  <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" status="status"/>

</apex:form>

<apex:outputPanel id="out">
        <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="testing...">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:detail relatedList="false" subject="{!listvalue}" title="false"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

==============
Controller:

```
public with sharing class soption09 
{
public list<selectoption> list1 = new list<selectoption>();
public list<Patient_Registration__c > list2 = new list<Patient_Registration__c >();
public Patient_Registration__c  value {get; set;}

public soption09(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
value=(Patient_Registration__c )controller.getRecord();
}
public PageReference test() {
            return null;
        }
public list<selectoption> getoptionlist()
{
 list2=[select id, Name from Patient_Registration__c ];
 list1.add(new selectoption('--Select options--', '--Select options--'));
 for(Patient_Registration__c pr:list2)
 {
   list1.add(new selectoption(pr.id,pr.Name));
 }
return list1;
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep adding to the `list1` List every time the VF page calls `getoptionlist`. If you change your logic so that you only initialize `list1` once then it will solve your problem.

```
public list<selectoption> list1;
...

public List<SelectOption> getoptionlist() {
    if (list1 == null) {
        list1 = new list<selectoption>()
        list1.add(new selectoption('--Select options--', '--Select options--'));
        for (Patient_Registration__c pr : [select id, Name from Patient_Registration__c ]) {
            list1.add(new selectoption(pr.id,pr.Name));
         }
     }

     return list1;
}
```

or if there was a valid reason for requerying Patient_Registration__c every time then you could do the following which will recreate `list1` every time rather than adding to it.

```
public List<SelectOption> getoptionlist() {
    list1 = new list<selectoption>()
    list1.add(new selectoption('--Select options--', '--Select options--'));
    for (Patient_Registration__c pr : [select id, Name from Patient_Registration__c ]) {
        list1.add(new selectoption(pr.id,pr.Name));
     }

     return list1;
}
```